# how tp pass some string from one url to another using redirect in flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask, url-routing

I have a `@app.route('/<data_select>')`, which can accept url like `'http://0.0.0.0:5000/valid_data' or 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/invalid_data'` . I have a `@app.route('/update_data', methods=['GET','POST'])` which handles both get and set request.

I want to pass some string from update_data->Post request to select_data-get request using redirect call. Here I have put my code

```
@app.route('/<data_select>')
def select_data(data_select):
    form = data() 
    return render_template('data.html', form= form)

@app.route('/update_data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def update_data():
    form = update_data() 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('update_data.html',form=form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        messages = "want to pass this string to select_data()"
        return redirect(url_for('valid_data',  messages = messages))
```

Please give me some idea

Comment: Please fix your indentation and confirm if this is the actual code you are using. Is this line correct? _`form = update_data()`_?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, yes this is the code hich I am using. '`form = update_data()' is defined in some other .py file,

Comment: `form = update_data()` is the same name as your method, this is very wrong, _especially if its defined in some other .py_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To present messages in flask, use [`flash`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/).

The example from the documentation explains it better than I could:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
     request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some_secret'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or \
                request.form['password'] != 'secret':
            error = 'Invalid credentials'
        else:
            flash('You were successfully logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Make sure you set the secret key (`app.secret_key`) because flash uses sessions and a key is required to encrypt the cookies.

In your templates:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>My Application</title>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass any string inside redirect something like return redirect(url_for('index', data = data)) ???? Can u plaese conform

Comment: You don't pass it in the redirect, you set it up before and then process it later - look at the example and read the documentation please, if then you don't understand it then ask a specific question.

Comment: I understood the flash message usage. Thank u :)